# JMeter ramp-up vs duration.

Tags: jmeter

Let's say that I have the current configuration :

```
Number of Threads (users): 150
Ramp-up : 30
Loop Count : None
```

If I add up a duration of 2 mins so  :

```
Number of Threads (users): 150
Ramp-up : 30
Loop Count : None
Duration (minutes) : 2
```

How does Jmeter going to react? If each Threads take about 10 seconds to complete

Thanks in advance

Comment: Loop Count is Forever? Duration is 120 seconds? Also you can check how JMeter react

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both Loop Count and Duration (if both present) are taken into account, **whichever comes first**. So in first configuration, you are not limiting loop count or duration, so the script will run "forever". In second case, loop count is still not limited, but duration is. So the test will stop 2 minutes after startup *of the very first user*, and the time includes ramp-up time. Stopping includes not running new samplers, and hard stop for all running samplers.

In your case, 150 users will *finish starting* after 30 sec. That means the first thread to run will complete 3 iterations (x10 sec) by the time the last thread just started its first.

Within the remaining 90 sec, all threads will complete roughly 8-9 iterations.

So for the first thread you should expect 11-12 iterations, for the very last thread to start, 8-9 iterations. Remaining threads anywhere between those numbers. Assuming ~30 threads executed same number of iterations, between 8 and 12, you get roughly 1500 iterations in total (could be a little over or under). Last iteration of each thread may be incomplete (e.g. some samplers did not get to run before test ran out of time).

Generally, since duration may leave unfinished iterations, I think it's only good as a fall back or threshold in pipeline automation. For example: run is configured to complete 1000 iterations (should take about 16 min if iteration takes 10 sec). So duration is set to 24 min (gives about 50% slack). It won't be needed if performance is decent, but if execution takes extremely long, we may hard stop it at 24 min, since there's no point to continue: we already know something is wrong.